# Creating a grah for java application

Tags: java, graph

`enter code here`I'm building an application that implements the A* algorithm to calculate a route between two rooms. I am trying to create a graph which the algorithm can operate of and I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. Here's what I've done so far:

Vect2.java:

```
package myalgorithm;

public class Vect2 {

    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Vect2(int x,int y ){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        }

}
```

Node.java

```
    package myalgorithm;




    public class Node {

        Node parent;
        Vect2 vector;
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public double f;
        public double g;
        public double h;


        public Node( int x,int y,Node parent, double g,double h){

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.parent= parent;
            this.g = g;
            this.h = h;
            this.f= this.g + this.h;

        }
    }

NodeGraph.java




 package myalgorithm;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class NodeGraph {

        Node a = new Node(88,623,null,0,0);
        Node b = new Node(727,627,null,0,0);
        Node c = new Node(723,93,null,0,0);
        Node d = new Node(90,92,null,0,0);
        Node e = new Node(94,349,null,0,0);
        Node f = new Node(397,358,null,0,0);
        Node g = new Node(722,339,null,0,0);
        Node[] arr = new Node[7];


    public NodeGraph init(){


        arr[0]= a;
        arr[0]= b;
        arr[0]= c;
        arr[0]= d;
        arr[0]= e;
        arr[0]= f;
        arr[0]= g;

        return this;
    }
    public void createMatrx(){
    boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[7][];
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) matrix[i] = new boolean[7];

    int nodeA = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, a);
    int nodeB = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, b);
    int nodeC = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, c);
    int nodeD = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, d);
    int nodeE = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, e);
    int nodeF = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, f);
    int nodeG = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, g);

    matrix[nodeA][nodeB] = true;
    matrix[nodeA][nodeE] = true;
    matrix[nodeB][nodeA] = true;
    matrix[nodeB][nodeG] = true;
    // A is connected to D
    matrix[nodeC][nodeG] = true;
    matrix[nodeC][nodeD] = true;
    // B is connected to D
    matrix[nodeD][nodeC] = true;
    matrix[nodeD][nodeE] = true;
    matrix[nodeE][nodeD] = true;
    // C is connected to D
    matrix[nodeE][nodeF] = true;
    matrix[nodeE][nodeA] = true;
    matrix[nodeF][nodeE] = true;
    matrix[nodeE][nodeG] = true;

    matrix[nodeG][nodeF] = true;
    matrix[nodeE][nodeB] = true;
    matrix[nodeE][nodeC] = true;

    matrix[nodeD][nodeC] = true;
    }
    }
```

Any suggestions on improvement will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fully understand what you do there but a few things strike me:

> arr[0]= a;
>           arr[0]= b;
>           arr[0]= c;
>           arr[0]= d;
>           arr[0]= e;
>           arr[0]= f;
>           arr[0]= g;

All are assigned to arr[0].
You may want to replace creation of `arr` with:

```
Node[] arr = new Node[]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g};
```

This also:

> ```
> boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[7][];
> for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) matrix[i] = new boolean[7];
> ```

You can do it like this:

```
    boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[7][7];
```